# Eclipse cannot see beyond Beans' models' fields from AbstractBean/AbstractEntity in Facelets

Tags: eclipse, generics, jsf, facelets, abstraction

I am running `jee-2019-06` version of Eclipse. Here is my Model-Bean-Facade structure:

I am not including getters/setters for brevity.

My Identifiable:

```
/** Identifiable interface for Entities; used for DAO - Service transitions. */
public interface Identifiable<T extends Serializable> extends Serializable {
    public T getId(); // identifiable field
    public String getTitle(); // user friendly name (maybe different from actual entity's name)
    public String getName(); // every entity has a name
    public String getDescription(); // every entity should have a description
}
```

My Abstract Bean:

```
public abstract class AbstractBean<T extends Identifiable<?>> {
    protected final transient Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
    private final Class<T> clazz;
    private T model;

    public AbstractBean(final Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    protected T createInstance() {
        try {
            return this.clazz.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            this.log.error("[" + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".createInstance()] : Error : {} {}", e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
    }
    protected AbstractFacade<T> getFacade() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

My Abstract Facade:

```
@Transactional
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T extends Identifiable<?>> {
    protected final transient Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
    protected final Class<T> clazz;

    public AbstractFacade(final Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
}
```

My Bean:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CarBean extends AbstractBean<Car> {
    @Inject
    private CarFacade facade;

    public CarBean(){
        super(Car.class);
    }

    @Override
    public CarFacade getFacade() {
        return this.facade;
    }
}
```

My AbstractEntity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Identifiable<Integer> {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String description;

    public AbstractEntity() {
    }
}
```

My Entity:

```
public class Car extends AbstractEntity {

    public Car() {
    }
}
```

I have no problems in showing the value to the user.

I have problems in validation and hyperlink in Eclipse:

```
<h:outputText value="#{carBean.model.name}" />
```

Facelet validator cannot validate `name` of `model`. It yellow underlines `name`. Also, I cannot `Ctrl + click` to activate hyperlink on `name`.

I saw on another developer's eclipse that both of my problems were not issues at all. I compared all the tools installed in both Eclipses and could not find anything relevant.

My question: what tools do I have to install or what settings/adjustments am I missing?

Please note: I do not want to disable the validator and I want to be able to hyperlink fields in facelet so that I will access the field using `Ctrl + click`.

Thank you.

Comment: ctrl-click on mode; works? Try adding jboss tools to eclipse and see if it makes a difference

Comment: I installed JBoss tools (all of them), my problem still persists.